# How do i properly implement a "read more" button in my php project?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In a part of a website i'm designing, there's this table that reads users messages from database and prints them in each row . What i'm asked to do is to make sure for every message longer than 50 characters , there's a "read more" button or link at the end of it and when its clicked it shows the entire message and then disappear it self . 
This is what I've done so far:

```
foreach ($message as $item) {
     echo '<tr><td>';
     if (strlen($item->text)>50){
          echo mb_substr($item->text,0,50).'<a href="#">readmore</a>';
     } else {
          echo $item->text;
     }
     echo '</td></tr>';
}
```

It show the first 50 characters of long messages plus the readmore link but i have no clue what else to do from here.

Comment: Count the characters with `strlen()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the full text in a hidden div which becomes visible when the 'readmore' link is clicked.

Example using jQuery:

```
foreach ($message as $item) {
 echo '<tr><td>';
 if (strlen($item->text)>50){
      echo mb_substr($item->text,0,50).'<a href="#" onclick="$(this).hide();$('#myId').show();">readmore</a>';
      echo '<div style="display:none;" id="myId">'. $item->text .'</div>';
 } else {
      echo $item->text;
 }
 echo '</td></tr>';
}
```

Make sure you're using a unique number instead of "myId"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if(strlen($item->text) > 50)
{
    echo echo substr($item->text, 50).'<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="content_trim">readmore</a>';
    echo '<p class="full_content" style="display:none;">'.$item->text.'</p>';
    // show the full content on the click of .content_trim
}
else
{
  echo $item->text;
}
```

The full text is present in a hidden div. Show it using `jquery` on the click of `.content_trim`